# Правила парсинга json в Java

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Должны ли названия полей класса и названия типов класса, к которому я парсю Json, полностью соответствовать названию полей, содержащихся в Json? И какие еще есть моменты, которые могут нарушить валидность парсинга?

```
SignInResponse response = gson.fromJson(result, SignInResponse.class);
```

После этой попытки парсинга приложение просто вылетает.

Comment: Названия полей могут и отличаться, но тогда нужно использовать аннотации. Вы лучше опишите конкретную проблему или ошибку с которой столкнулись. Так будет легче вам помочь.

Comment: дополнила вопрос

Comment: Я бы посоветовал использовать библиотеку org.json

Comment: Ну теперь добавьте содержание класса `SignInResponse` значение `result` и стектрейс полученной ошибки.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin попробовал использовать библиотеку org.json - это лучшее решение, спасибо, что направили на нужный путь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию должны совпадать, но Вы можете это поменять. Наиболее простой путь -- это применить общий шаблон именования для всех полей. Если Вы используете Gson, то за это отвечает енам `FieldNamingPolicy`. Используя `FieldNamingPolicy` Вы, например, можете нормально десериализовывать JSON с pascal-case полями в Java-объекты, у которых имена полей обычно в camel-case. Устанавливается `FieldNamingPolicy` примерно так:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
    .create();
```

Загляните в [документацию](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html), там наверняка есть подходящая для вашего случая политика.

Если по какой-то причине у Вас в джсоне различный шаблон нейминга в одном объекте или какие-нибудь неприятные аббревиатуры, то можно использовать аннотации, которыми можно явно задать ключ, по которому данное поле доступно в JSON. В Gson это аннотация [`SerializedName`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) (по ссылке есть простой пример использования).